# how to pipe multi commands to bash?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, xargs

I want to check some file on the remote website.

Here is bash command to generate commands that calculate the file md5

```
[root]# head -n 3 zrcpathAll | awk '{print $3}' | xargs -I {} echo wget -q -O - -i {}e \| md5sum\;
wget -q -O - -i https://example.com/zrc/3d2f0e76e04444f4ec456ef9f11289ec.zrce | md5sum;
wget -q -O - -i https://example.com/zrc/e1bd7171263adb95fb6f732864ceb556.zrce | md5sum;
wget -q -O - -i https://example.com/zrc/5300b80d194f677226c4dc6e17ba3b85.zrce | md5sum;
```

Then I pipe the outputed commands to bash, but only the first command was executed.

```
[root]# head -n 3 zrcpathAll | awk '{print $3}' | xargs -I {} echo wget -q -O - -i {}e \| md5sum\; | bash -v
wget -q -O - -i https://example.com/zrc/3d2f0e76e04444f4ec456ef9f11289ec.zrce | md5sum;
3d2f0e76e04444f4ec456ef9f11289ec  -
[root]#
```

Comment: Why are you piping the `xargs` output to `bash`?  Instead, replace `echo` with `bash -c` (and build the string appropriately).  In other words, let `xargs` do its job and execute the commands for you.

Comment: Thank you, it works with `head -n 3 zrcpathAll | awk '{print $3}' | xargs -I {} bash -vc 'wget -q -O - '{}'e | md5sum';`. If I remove the `-i` parameter in my question, it also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following instead:

```
while read -r _ _ url _; do
    wget -q -O - "$url"e | md5sum
done < <(head -n 3 zrcpathAll)
```

we should not put `-i` in front of "$url" here.

**[Explanation about -i option]**

Manpage of `wget` says:

> -i file
> --input-file=file
> Read URLs from a local or external file. [snip]
> If this function is used, no URLs need be present on the command line. [snip]
> If the file is an external one, the document will be automatically treated as html if the Content-Type matches text/html.
> Furthermore, the file's location will be implicitly used as base
> href if none was specified.

where the `file` will contain line(s) of url such as:

```
https://example.com/zrc/3d2f0e76e04444f4ec456ef9f11289ec.zrce
https://example.com/zrc/e1bd7171263adb95fb6f732864ceb556.zrce
https://example.com/zrc/5300b80d194f677226c4dc6e17ba3b85.zrce
```

Whereas if we use the option as `-i url`, `wget` first
downloads the `url` as a file which contains the lines of urls
as above. In our case, the `url` is the target to download itself,
not the list of urls, `wget` causes an error: `No URLs found in url`.

Even if the `wget` fails, why the command outputs just one line, not
three lines as the result of `md5sum`?
This seems to be because the `head` command immediately flushes the remaining
lines when the piped subprocess fails.

Comment: It's same, only execute the first.  ```# while read -r _ _ url _; do
>     wget -q -O - -i "$url"e | md5sum
> done < <(head -n 3 zrcpathAll)
3d2f0e76e04444f4ec456ef9f11289ec  -
[root]#```

Comment: What are the `>` after `do` and after `md5sum` in your comment?

Comment: It means new line. I just copy your code, and paste in my console.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've found the mistake. We should not have put `-i` option in front of the valid url. Would you please try the updated script? Regards.

Comment: Thank you. It works both your answer and mine when I remove the `-i` parameter. Can you explain it?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Good to know it works including your original
command line. My apology for taking a time to find the essential problem
lies in the usage of `-i` option, not the `xargs` command. I've updated
my answer with an explanation of `-i` option. BR.